# UseBrowserLink Error while trying to build a project in ASP.NET Core in VS 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, telerik, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to Build a web Project that uses `ASP.NET` CORE Framework.

In the start.cs file I'm getting compile time error near `app.UseBrowserLink()` and I don't know why. I didn't make any changes on that file.

> "Error  CS0121  The call is ambiguous between the following methods
>   or properties:
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.BrowserLinkExtensions.UseBrowserLink(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IApplicationBuilder)'
>   and
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.BrowserLinkLoaderExtensions.UseBrowserLink(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IApplicationBuilder)'    MyPage  C:\Users\adduria\Source\Repos\TelerikUI\MyPage\src\MyPage\Startup.cs    49  Active"

Can you please help me with that?

Comment: Did you upgrade any packages recently? An old `BrowserLink` DLL might still be in your `bin` folder. Try deleting the `bin` folder and rebuilding your project.

Answer (score 9):

Check your Nuget, you might have both the 
`Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink` and `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowerLink.Loader` packages referenced. Remove the `Loader` one.

[image: Nuget - BrowserLink]

Answer (score 3):

Same error for me on Visual Studio 2017, v15.9.10, using .NET Core 2.1. I solved it by installing the following NuGet packages, in order:

1. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions v2.1.1
2. Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink v2.1.1

The package version you need will depend on the project's .NET Core version. As far as I can tell, you have to guess. Give it your best shot, and if the install fails the error message will sometimes tell you which version to install, or that you've picked a version that's too low. Use the clues in the error messages to zero in on the correct version.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error on visual Studio 2017. To solve this problem:

- Install Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink 2.2.0
- Rebuild your project

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the following dependencies:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink
Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical
Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Abstractions
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal
Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Core
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions
Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool
Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities
Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions
Microsoft.Extensions.Options
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions
System.ComponentModel.Annotations
Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features
Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives
```